# Add multiple documents and receive the ID in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, sqlite, google-cloud-firestore

How can I read the result of a list of documents after performing several save operations as a single batch in Firestore?

I need to receive the document data to delete the registration in SQLite after sending it to Firestore. My application needs to work offline and send all documents at once when I have internet.

I'm sending this way (code below) but it's taking a long time to send all the data

```
    List<Record> notUpdate = recordService.getNotUpdate();

    for (Record record : notUpdate) {

        Map<String, Object> field = new HashMap<>();
        field.put("operator", driverService.getByID(record.getFk_driver()).getName());
        field.put("operator_id", driverService.getByID(record.getFk_driver()).getUid());
        field.put("status", record.getStatus());
        field.put("fleet_type", sessionService.getDevice().getFkFleet());
        field.put("equipment", sessionService.getEquipment().getName());
        field.put("equipment_id", sessionService.getEquipment().getUid());
        field.put("device_id", sessionService.getDevice().getUid());
        field.put("date", DateUtilService.convertLongToTimestamp(record.getDate()));
        field.put("location", new GeoPoint(10, 20));

        collection.add(field)
                .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
                    recordService.delete(record);

                    if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
                        Listener listener = (Listener) activity;
                        listener.onRecordUpdateListener();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(Throwable::printStackTrace);
    }
```

I read [Firestore multiple write operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), but it seems that with WriteBatch I can't read the documents, just send them. If anyone knows of another solution I will be grateful.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that reads data from Firestore. I'm only seeing a list of `Record` objects.

Comment: this way I can delete using the Record object, because I send one at a time, but I still receive the documentReference in the addOnSuccessListener with the data from the inserted document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're saying is true - a batch can only write data.  It can't read them.  If you want to read documents after writing them, you will have to wait for the batch write to finish, then execute queries to read the written documents.  There's no simple workaround for this.